# Spacing not working in table with if statements PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, spacing

I have built a table from a MYSQL database using PHP. There are 4 columns that are checked whether they have `yes` in them and only displayed if so. The only problem is that when the first column `repair` has nothing in it, but a subsequent column has a `yes`, they display outputs the `yes` into the `repair` column instead of leaving a blank spot there and putting it under it's correct column. The column header appears correctly, its just getting the data to appear in the correct column. Not sure how to go about this so any help appreciated.

```
//build table for results
echo "<table><tr>";
echo "<th>Part Number</th>";
echo "<th>Serial Number</th>";
echo "<th>Date</th>";

//check whether each element has data
//and only display is data present
if ($repair=="yes") echo "<th>Repair</th>";
if ($upgrade=="yes") echo "<th>Upgrade</th>";
if ($pm=="yes") echo "<th>PM</th>";
if ($nofault=="yes") echo "<th>No Fault</th></tr>";

// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$part=$row['part'];
$serial=$row['serial'];
$date=$row['date'];
$Repair=$row['repair'];
$Upgrade=$row['upgrade'];
$PM=$row['pm'];
$NoFault=$row['nofault'];

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>$part</td>";
echo "<td>$serial</td>";
echo "<td>$date</td>";
if ($Repair=="yes") echo "<td>YES</td>";
if ($Upgrade=="yes") echo "<td>YES</td>";
if ($PM=="yes") echo "<td>YES</td>";
if ($NoFault=="yes") echo "<td>YES</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should include empty cells for when the if evaluates to false. something like this:

```
if ($Repair == "yes") {
 echo "<td>yes</td>"
} else {
 echo "<td></td>"
}
```

You could also echo the value directly in the td in this case. Something like this:

```
echo "<td>";
if ($Repair == "yes") echo $Repair;
echo "</td>";
```

Comment: Thanks that works really well. On a side note, where I now have blank columns, can I change my CSS or PHP to make it a very small width so it doesnt have a large gap there? At the moment my table width is all automatic spacing.

Comment: Actually got it sorted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This logic might help

```
if ($repair=="yes") echo "<th>Repair</th>" else echo "<th>&nbsp;</th>";
```

Same down the code

```
if ($Repair=="yes") echo "<td>YES</td>" else echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to output the `<td></td>` either way. The style of code you're using is a terrible mess (tons of echo statements with double quoted HTML strings). Here's a better way:

```
//build table for results

?>

<table>

<tr>
<th>Part Number</th>
<th>Serial Number</th>
<th>Date</th>

<?php

//check whether each element has data
//and only display is data present
if ($repair=="yes") echo "<th>Repair</th>";
if ($upgrade=="yes") echo "<th>Upgrade</th>";
if ($pm=="yes") echo "<th>PM</th>";
if ($nofault=="yes") echo "<th>No Fault</th></tr>";

// printing table rows
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {

?>

<tr>

<td><?php echo $part; ?></td>

<td><?php echo $serial; ?></td>

<td><?php echo $date; ?></td>

<td><?php echo $row[ 'Repair' ] == "yes" ? "YES" : ""; ?></td>

<td><?php echo $row[ 'Upgrade' ] == "yes" ? "YES" : ""; ?></td>

<td><?php echo $row[ 'PM' ] == "yes" ? "YES" : ""; ?></td>

<td><?php echo $row[ 'NoFault' ] == "yes" ? "YES" : ""; ?></td>

</tr>

<?php

}
// while

?>

</table>
```